# PHP JSON consulta sin ""

Tags: php, json

Disculpen no supe como explicarme en el titulo; lo que requiero es quitar unas comillas de una consulta JSON. En esta consulta obtengo lo siguiente:

```
Hago una consulta en un php a la base de datos y esa respuesta le hago un json_encode este es el codigo:

    $sql = "SELECT title, latitude, longitude, color, pml_mda FROM npa.coordenadas_zona_carga, pend where npa.coordenadas_zona_carga.title = npa.pend.zona_carga;";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows >0) 
    {
    // aqui feutch los datos
$final_array = array ();    
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())   
        {
        $arr = array('title'   =>$row['title'],
                    'latitude'   =>$row['latitude'],
                    'longitude' =>$row['longitude'],
                    'color' =>$row['color'],
                    'pml' =>$row['pml_mda']
                     );
    $final_array [] = $arr;
        }
//convierte los datos en formato json
 return json_encode ($final_array);
}    
else 
{
    echo "fallo";
}
$conn->close();
```

Esto lo consulto asi:

```
<?php $json_data = include ('consultas/mapa_pend.php'); 
 echo $json_data;
```

El resultado es

> [{"title":"ACAPULCO","latitude":"16.852299","longitude":"-99.909317","color":"colorSet.next()","pml":"482.8"},{"title":"AGUASCALIENTES","latitude":"21.884501","longitude":"-102.292534","color":"colorSet.next()","pml":"442.51"}
>
> Asi se soluciono gracias a todos por ayudarme en el orden y estructura de mis preguntas y su apoyo para solucionar mi problema gracias
>
> latitude' =>(float)$row['latitude']

---

Comment: Hola @Joaquin Duran ¿podrías editar tu pregunta agregando el fragmento de código donde muestras como devuelves tu json de respuesta? No podemos ayudarte hasta no ver como lo haces

Comment: Convierte el dato a número: `'latitude' => (float)$row['latitude'],`.

Comment: Exactamente es lo que buscaba muchas gracias amigo.

Comment: Si en la Base de Datos esas columnas son de tipo `FLOAT`, puedes indicar a mysqli que preserve los tipos de datos configurando esta opción: `$conn->options(MYSQLI_OPT_INT_AND_FLOAT_NATIVE, 1);` [Revisa el Manual de PHP para más detalles](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.options.php) así te los pondrá como tales en los resultados.

Comment: Si quisiera quitarle también las "" a el campo "color":"ColorNet()"
por "color":ColorNext() sin las comillas ¿Como lo podria realizar?