# Remover "" comillas de resultado JSON

Tags: javascript, php, json

Hago una consulta en un php a la base de datos y esa respuesta le hago un json_encode este es el codigo:

```
    $sql = "SELECT title, latitude, longitude, color, pml_mda FROM npa.coordenadas_zona_carga, pend where npa.coordenadas_zona_carga.title = npa.pend.zona_carga;";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows >0) 
    {
    // aqui feutch los datos
$final_array = array ();    
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())   
        {
    $arr = array('title'   =>$row['title'],
                'latitude'   =>$row['latitude'],
                'longitude' =>$row['longitude'],
                'color' =>$row['color'],
                'pml' =>$row['pml_mda']
                 );
    $final_array [] = $arr;
        }
//convierte los datos en formato json
 return json_encode ($final_array);
}    
else 
{
    echo "fallo";
}
$conn->close();
```

Esto se consulta desde otro archivo que grafica:

```
<?php $json_data = include ('consultas/mapa_pend.php'); 
 echo $json_data;
```

El resultado es

```
"title":"ACAPULCO","latitude":"16.852299","longitude":"-99.909317","color":"colorSet.next()","pml":"482.8"},{"title":"AGUASCALIENTES","latitude":"21.884501","longitude":"-102.292534","color":"colorSet.next()","pml":"442.51"}
```

Quiero quitarle las comillas al resultado del campo "color"
Para pasar de
"color":"ColorSet.Next()"
a "color":ColorSet.Next() ->sin comillas.

Comment: Ya hiciste la misma pregunta [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/494805/php-json-consulta-sin)

Comment: Si ya me la solucionaron con los INT pero lo que quiero es quitarle las "" al STR si se puede o seria ya dentro del javascript? la verdad es que soy muy nuevo gracias

Comment: no puedes hacer eso, ,lo que estás devolviendo es un objeto json, la cual, por naturaleza, encierra la clave y el valor en comillas, lee más acerca de esto por internet, si lo que deseas es quitarle las comillas, mejor cambia el valor de color para que lo regreses como lo quieres, `"title":"ACAPULCO","latitude":"16.852299","longitude":"-99.909317","color":"colorSet.next()","pml":"482.8"},{"title":"AGUASCALIENTES","latitude":"21.884501","longitude":"-102.292534","color":"'color':ColorSet.Next()","pml":"442.51"}` Si invocas al índice `color` debería devolverte algo como `'color':ColorSet.Next()`

Comment: creo que así como lo quieres no se puede, por que al desrealizar el js te generara un error de que es invalido, mas bien puedes generar el color desde  el php y regresarlo en el js como "color": "#000000", o mandarlo así y en el cliente asignar la propiedad o lo que necesites hacer con ese colorset.

Comment: creo tendria que poner el ejemplo del javascript lo actualizo. 
Si cuando lo intento me lo transforma en 0.
Lo que voy ha hacer poner el valor= SetColor.next()